# Must the $x$ and $y$ axes have the same units? (Coordinate Geomtry)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I was thinking of this for quite a time now, but never have seemed to get a direct answer. If I have a system of coordinate axes, namely $x$ and $y$. Must the units on the $x$-axis be the same length as the units on the $y$-axis? What exactly changes? Is this some unique relation between the axes? I've never been properly introduced to this yet. And when the two axes are measured in two different units entirely, when graphing the sine function, for example (the $y$-axis is measured in degrees while the $x$-axis is measured in real units). Could someone please guide me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don’t understand your example. In calculus, when we write $\sin\theta$, $\theta$ is a purely real number (written n radians) without dimensions.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about when you say that the y-axis is measured in degrees while the x-axis is measured with real numbers for a sine function. The function $f(x)=\sin x$ takes in a real number $x$ and returns another real number $\sin x$ which is then plotted on the Cartesian plane. Both axes are measured with real numbers.

Comment: Within the realm of math, there aren't any units in the normal-English definition. "Unit" just means "one," though it can mean different kinds of one depending on the setting. Shift over to applications of math in the sciences, and of course you can have different units on both axes! In fact it's very important to specify which units go with which axis!

Comment: My question was: can the two coordinate axes be scaled differently (in pure mathematics)? If yes, would all the formulas for equally-scaled rectangular axes apply to the differently scaled rectangular axes? E.g, finding the gradient, or angle between to straight lines.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If x,y scales are equal a circle gives the appearance of the circle. If scaling is different in x,y axes a circle looks like an ellipse.

Computed physical quantities on the basis of a relation, formula do not change. But *what you see* in scaled coordinates plots is different because then you tend to ignore the unequal scalings and still see with equal scalings basis.